# Jquery auto refresh with pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination

I created a system of pagination with jquery, the script works very well but when I change page the script made me go back to the original page because of the refresh.

How to make refresh works with pagination?

thank you

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#results" ).load( "recherche.php"); 
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show(); 
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
        $("#results").load("recherche.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
            $(".loading-div").hide(); 

            });

        });

    }, 1000);
});

<div id="results">
<div class="loading-div">
<img src="img/loader.gif">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the script made me go back to the original page because of the refresh" exactly? You mean page 2 loads, and then page one loads "on top" of it again? And what is returned by recherche.php?

Comment: well... you'd have to actually write a pagination system that can either manager itself in the *session* on server side, or keep the page in the url. in both case it's a total rewrite of what you have here...

Comment: @MacPrawn Yes, when I want to go to the next page (example: page.php?=Page2) my script that executes the refresh "setInterval function ()" brings me back to the original page (page.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the additional details in the comments. I believe your problem is "setInterval"... You probably want to run this code only **once**, on page load - then the ajax calls will take over.

In that case, you need to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) - [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) will repeat the callback every 1000 milliseconds. (in this case)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#results" ).load( "recherche.php"); 
        $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".loading-div").show(); 
            var page = $(this).attr("data-page");
            $("#results").load("recherche.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
                $(".loading-div").hide(); 

            });
        });
    }, 1000);
});

<div id="results">
    <div class="loading-div">
        <img src="img/loader.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT**

All right, so if you do want to refresh your page every second, (that's very often!) then you will need to remember the current page you are on, so that future calls load the right page, always. You should use a variable to hold the current page value, default it to "page 1" and voila!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentPage = 1;
    var loadPage = function(page) {
        $(".loading-div").show();

        page = page || currentPage; // if no page parameter provided, simply reload the currentPage

        $("#results").load("recherche.php",{"page":page}, function(){ 
            currentPage = page; // once the page is loaded, update our currentPage value since this is the page we are now looking at

            $(".loading-div").hide();
        });
    };

    // Move this out of the interval - you probably don't want to set-up a click handler every time your interval is called!
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        loadPage($(this).attr("data-page"));
    });

    setInterval(function(){
        loadPage(); // every 1 second, reload the current page
    }, 1000);

    loadPage(1); // initial loading of the first page
});

<div class="loading-div">
    <img src="img/loader.gif">
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

One last thing to note: the very first time you load your content, it will override the "results" div's content - including your loader.gif... I've moved the loader outside your results div so it can be re-used every time you request a new page...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to refresh my page every 1seconds. Not even once...

Comment: Super, I removed the .gif because otherwise it displays it at each refresh.

It works very well thank you very much you're the best :)

Comment: Awesome. So if you don;t mind, it'd help me out if you marked my answer as accepted... ;) Thanks!